# Find and Replace word filter Gmail

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail

I am fairly new to Java, but also brand new to google script. I really want to make a simple program to filter incoming email and replace one word with another and tag it as having been changed, probably with a traditional gmail tag. Basically, I just had my name changed and hate my old one, so I want to replace it with my new name and have a mark like "Changed name". Any ideas where to start? Any help is great. Thank you!

Comment: You want to send email as a different name?

Answer (score 1):

It is is not possible to modify the content of an email messages in Gmail using Google Apps Script.